# event.target.id as undefined ? Creating dynamic buttons using backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a `section` element with `id = wrapper`. In my router I add `.delegate()` jQuery method to delegate events to dynamically created buttons (as traditional `events:{"click button" : "gotoSomeMethod"}` is not working for me).

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 window.App = new window.Routers.Package;
 Backbone.history.start();              

   $('#wrapper').delegate("button", "click", function(ev){
      alert ($(ev.target).id); 
   });
});
```

Here is my view,

```
window.Views.Actions = Backbone.View.extend({
tag: 'nav',

initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'gotoNode');


},

render:function(){
    this.model.each(function(action){
        var buttonTemplate = "<button id = '"  + action.toNodeId + "'>" + action.name + "     </button>";
        $(this.el).append(buttonTemplate)
    }, this);


    console.log(this.el); // when I do this I get `<div><button id = 'something'></button></div>`
    return this;
},

   events:{
      "click button":"gotoNode"  
   },

   gotoNode:function() {
     alert("inside gotoNode");  
   },

});
```

So the first issue here is why I get undefined as an for `id`? Secondly, how do I make backbone to call `gotoNode()` method?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery function `$` returns a `jQuery` object, not the DOMElement. If you want to access the id of that element you need to use `$(ev.target).attr("id")`. Also you shouldn't use `ev.target`. It returns the DOMElement that was clicked and it can be the button, but it can also be the TextNode inside the button. In the second case you won't have the id attribute. What you need to use is `$(this).attr("id")`.

For the `gotoNode` part, it would make more sense if you where doing the event binding in your view (move the delegate call inside your initialize method).

```
initialize : function () {
     _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'gotoNode');

    var self = this;

    $('#wrapper').delegate("button", "click", function(ev){
        self.gotoNode();
    });
}
```

Comment: Declaring inside render function sure works but then it goes into loop as I am creating multiple buttons. So for one click I will get like 15 alert boxes. Besides, `$(ev.target).attr("id")` works too.

Comment: @Eric I'm not saying `$(ev.target).attr("id")` doesn't work. I'm saying it can return you unexcepted result and it would be by design. For your second question, I've updated my answer. I'm not sure if that's exactly what you want to do, if it's not you should provide more context.

Comment: @HolyViewr The function has to be delegate (previous answer was correct) but it cannot be inside render method as in the code render is called to generate button respective to the actions mentioned in the JSON file that I am reading. That means if 10 actions are mentioned in the JSON file 10 buttons will be created. Now as the buttons are dynamically created, and id's along with name are assigned dynamically so I should be able to know which button was clicked. Hence, I want the button id, which now I am getting, and the function gotoNode should be called only...

Comment: .. once per click. In my case (if I add delegate function inside render) for one click it is been called 10 times.

Comment: If you need to stay with delegate it would probably make more sense to leave the delegate bind in the initialize method then. See update.

Comment: Yup, I tried that too but again for one click it alerts 10 times.

Comment: @Eric Are you initializing your view more than once ? If you do so you will end up with lot's of listener on your button. Delegate will bind event for all the button that will be added in the future. In that case you need to use undelegate once you are done with an instance of your view.

Comment: Yes, I am initializing my view more than once. Is undelegate similar to delegate?

Comment: delegate events are bounds to element even if they are added after your delegate call. Which means that if you call delegate more than once, you will have more than one listener on your button even if they are added at different point in time. `undelegate` is there to remove all the previous listener.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `gotoNode()` method to work you must place your button into `this.el`. Only then delegate will work.